# find number of disjoint subsets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

For my discrete maths course i did the following exercise:

*Let M be a finite set with n elements, find*

$|\{(U,V)|U,V\subseteq M , U \not = V,U\cap V= \emptyset \}|$

I did it the following way:
choose a set $C\subseteq M$ and then partion $C$ into two sets. There are ${n}\choose{k}$ ways to choose $C$ with cardinality $k$. $C$ has $2^k$ subsets and if $k>0$ then these subsets come in $2^{k-1}$ complementary pairs. So $C$ can be split int two disjoint subsets in $2^{k-1}$ ways. And altogether there are then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} {{n}\choose{k}}2^{k-1}
$$
However, i do not understand my approach anymore. Why are there $2^{k-1}$ complementary pairs. And also wouldn't it be possible to combine $C$ with any subset of $M\backslash C$ such that we would reach
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} {{n}\choose{k}}2^{n-k}
$$
any help in trying to understand my thoughts from one year ago would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you factor in that $k$ can be $0$, then $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}2^{n-k}$ is the right answer, since it’s equal to $3^n$ due to the binomial theorem.

Comment: Once you have chosen U a subset of C (2^k possibilities), there is only one way to choose the complementary V of U in C to form a partition of C. So in total $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right)2^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right)2^k-1=3^n-1$

Comment: I missed $U\ne V$, the answer is $3^n-1$ indeed.

Comment: Another way to see $3^n-1$ is to note that each element $i\in M$ appears in $U$, $V$, or neither ($3^n$ choices), but we must exclude $U=V=\emptyset$.